# Bash - Same commented line each time I launch a bash terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, unix

It's been nearly a year that, each time a launch my bash terminal I get the following line at the beginning :

[image]

```
## cd /Users/Julien/Documents/ENSIIE/Projets/S4/MESIM_Rendu1/wetransfer-19f358/Random ##
```

I never knew why was it printed and I did use this command more then a year ago. Why is it printed and how can I remove it ?

EDIT (Randomhero's answer) : I did not find this line or nothing else similar in my `.bashrc`before asking this question

EDIT 2 (DavidPostill's comment) : 
I also checked : 
    $BASH_ENV (empty)
    $ENV (empty)
    $CDPATH (empty)
    $GLOBIGNORE (empty)

```
~/.bash_login (empty)
~/.profile (exactly same code as .bashrc)


$SHELLOPTS
```

`braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor`

```
$BASHOPTS
```

`checkwinsize:cmdhist:complete_fullquote:expand_aliases:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:login_shell:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath`

Comment: Check the rest of your [bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill I edited my question according to your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go on ~/ then try:

```
grep -rn "19f358/Random"
```

It might help you to find where this line comes from.

If you find nothing, it means it's not hard written somewhere so this line might be created.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and welcome to StackExchange - Super User ! I did what you suggest, I had this warning ```grep: warning: recursive search of stdin``` and the code is still running. There's something weird, my activity monitor (```system-monitor``` or ```htop``` on Linux) shows me that there is not much running tasks on my terminal whereas the grep commands is still running. I'll be back to you if it terminates.

Comment: @J.Khamphousone `-r` is not required by POSIX, I guess different implementations of `grep` may behave differently when there is no directory specified. Some search in the current working directory (and it seems the answer assumes this behavior). It looks your `grep` uses stdin. Try `grep -rn "19f358/Random" ~/`.

Comment: I got a load of theses messages : ```grep: /Users/Julien//.julia/v0.6/Homebrew/deps/usr/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/fuse/osxfuse.pc: No such file or directory``` with theses ones too : ```grep: /Users/Julien//Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/DC/Reader/Synchronizer/Commands: Operation not supported on socket``` and theses too : ```grep: warning: /Users/Julien//Library/Containers/com.apple.PressAndHold/Data/Movies/Bibliothèque iMovie.imovielibrary/.fcpcache: recursive directory loop```

Comment: It's still running after half an hour and I have hundreds of those messages. I stop it, I can relaunch it for something like 6 hours tomorrow if you think it's working.

Comment: Try with sudo...

Answer (score 1):

I would check your bashrc file (usually found at ~/.bashrc) and see if there is a line in that file. It looks like it is calling an ECHO command to show the line. You can either comment out the whole line, or you can delete it. It isn't doing anything by the looks of it.

Feel free to paste the line to be checked before you take any action on it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I did check into my ```.bashrc```if this line was in there before I asked my question, and I didn't find it. I edited my question according to your answer